# Running a local development evm virtual machine

Tags: evm

Is there a way to compile, run and debug a solidity class on my developpment computer.

I do not want to connect to an ethereum network.

I just want to debug my class

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) for development and testing without installing a node or connecting to a remote node (docs [here](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).
It's a development tool that you can use straight from the browser.

Comment: In fact i do not want to work with the browser. There are no command line tools?

Comment: [ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) and [solc](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) for contract compilation or [truffle suite](https://www.trufflesuite.com/)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to compile, run and debug a solidity class on my developpment computer.

[You can use Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  and compile, run, debug and test smart contracts locally.

Answer (score 1):

[Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) is another great option if you are familiar with javascript.

You can use hardhat framework to compile your contract, run blockchain network locally, write tests against your contract, etc.